# Connecting to a paired BLE Device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can't figure out how to connect to a BLE device from a WP app.  More specifically, I want to go from the paired state, to being connected.
If I do this from the Bluetooth setting page in the phone, the my app works just fine.
What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can read a characteristic(ex: GAP Device Name) value with `uncached mode` as a connect method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothcachemode.aspx

Windows will trying to retrieve connection.

If read success, represent the connection is established.

If read fail, represent can't connect to remote device.

Comment: Because the Windows pnp mechanism, the device connection and disconnection is controlled by Windows. 
So, I don't know how to implement other workarounds